# How to get facebook page id via php?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-page

Suppose i have a facebook page link `http://facebook.com/page_name` and i am not the admin of the page. Is it possible to find out the facebook id, profile pics of the page and fan count?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FB id and some informations: yes. See [Graph API docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/).

**edit:**
Some code to get id from my app:

```
$arg = $_REQUEST['arg'];
if ($arg != ''){

        $arg = str_replace(
                array('http://','www.','facebook.com/','/'),
                '',
                $arg
        );

        $elseID = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/?ids='.$arg.'&fields=id');
        $elseID = json_decode($elseID,true);
        $elseID = $elseID[$arg]['id'];
}
```

Comment: thanks! but i always have found facebook documentation really hard :(

Comment: Thanks! You both gives great answer i don't know whom to select the best. I will flip a coin :)

Answer (score 3):

Typically you can do http://graph.facebook.com/{page_name} and receive the appropriate results. For example, Pepsi is at http://www.facebook.com/pepsi and you can see the graph API results at https://graph.facebook.com/pepsi.

Comment: Yep. Pretty much straight JSON, use your favorite library (in PHP, `$info = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.facebook.com/pepsi"));` works).

Comment: Thanks! You both gives great answer i don't know whom to select the best. I will flip a coin :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Facebook SDK for PHP https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk

Below my solution

```
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;

$pageUrl = 'some_url';  
      FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('facebookAppId','facebookAppSecret');
    //getting session
    $Session = FacebookSession::newAppSession();
    try
    {
      //validating if session is correct
      $Session->validate();
      //sending request
      $Request = new FacebookRequest($Session, 'GET', '/',
                                      array (
                                        'id' => $pageUrl,
                                      )
                                    );
      $Response = $Request->execute();
      //getting UserGraph object
      $UserObject = $Response->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
      //return page id
      return $UserObject->GetId();
    }
    catch (FacebookRequestException $ex)
    {}
    catch (Exception $ex)
    {}
```